# DbSet Not available in Nunit

Tags: c#, nunit, dbset

I am trying to do Mock test of a function which is invoking Entity db set.
e.g.

```
Customer c= appcontext.Customer  (w=> w.custid=11).tolist();
```

in my Unit test I am trying to follow the steps as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking

However when I am trying to do

```
var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Customer >>();
```

Visual studio can not find DbSet . I have included System.Data.Entity

help needed.
Thanks.

Comment: Your code won't compile.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: As per `moq` defination, it says `first test` then `mock` which means the `moq` works only with already tested `code` to just `mock` it. For details you can watch this series. 
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6tu16kXT9Pq6aZHjfWYYkM6d3gGfb_uy